# Stop numbers from going over 1 decimal place

Tags: actionscript-3, math

Title.

I have a text box/label in my world that can be changed in increments of 0.1, but I get numbers like:

8.000000000001

```
myTextField.text = "YGravity: " + ygrav + " XGravity: " + xgrav;
```

I've tried and using math.ceil & floor, but it the numbers are wrong (ygravity says 0 but the objects are still raising/ falling)

Comment: Show more code.  how do set and use `ygrav` & `xgrav`other than the 1 line you've shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of floating point decimals - they can round off in weird ways (I don't recall why it happens, but it does).  You can fix it by rounding to a specific decimal place.  If your numbers increment by .1 then you should only need one decimal place. `YGravity: " + ygrav.toFixed(1) + " XGravity: " + xgrav.toFixed(1)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a number to 1 decimal place, I suggest something like:

```
//your number with lots of decimals
var ygrav:Number = 1.23456;

//multiply the number by 10, then round it off the way you want
var roundedYgrav:Number = Math.round(ygrav*10);

//roundedYgrav should now be 12. Now your final number is the rounded number divided by 10
var displayYgrav:Number = roundedYgrav/10;

//displayYgrav is now 1.2
myTextField.text = "YGravity: " + displayYgrav;
```

Comment: use `toFixed` instead, all this rounding and dividing is just unneeded overhead

Comment: I guess toFixed is great, but I like to keep my numbers as numbers. "just in case" :p